# iOS: sqlite3 runtime function always returning 0 (where double is expected)

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, fmdb

I have implemented the algorithm provided by the brilliant Dave Addey to calculate the distance between two coordinates using the "spherical law of cosines" formula (this is the [original link](http://daveaddey.com/?p=71)). This is how I intend to use the function call in a query:

```
NSString *SQLQuery= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT distance(lat, lon, '%f', '%f') as distance, * FROM table WHERE distance < %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, distance/1000.0];
```

The problem is that I can correctly filter the results in a radius of 1km, but when I try to access the column "distance" it always returns 0. I am using the FMDatabase, but direct calls to sqlite3 (`[resultset doubleForColumnIndex: 0]`) doesn't fix the issue.

Here is the code used to declare the function (I tried with direct calls to sqlite3 too):

```
    [database makeFunctionNamed:@"distance"
               maximumArguments:4
                      withBlock: ^( sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv ) {
                          // check that we have four arguments (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
                          assert(argc == 4);
                          // check that all four arguments are non-null
                          if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[1]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[2]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[3]) == SQLITE_NULL) {
                              sqlite3_result_null(context);
                              return;
                          }
                          // get the four argument values
                          double lat1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
                          double lon1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[1]);
                          double lat2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[2]);
                          double lon2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[3]);
                          // convert lat1 and lat2 into radians now, to avoid doing it twice below
                          double lat1rad = DEG2RAD(lat1);
                          double lat2rad = DEG2RAD(lat2);
                          // apply the spherical law of cosines to our latitudes and longitudes, and set the result appropriately
                          // 6378.1 is the approximate radius of the earth in kilometres
                          double distance = acos(sin(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) + cos(lat1rad) * cos(lat2rad) * cos(DEG2RAD(lon2) - DEG2RAD(lon1))) * 6378.1;
                          sqlite3_result_double(context, distance);
                      }];
```

Any clues?

Comment: Problem might be here:
distance(lat, lon, '%f', '%f') - you're passing '%f' instead of %f here, so, perhaps, sqlite actually converts your floats to characters and than casts them to zero, nullifying all your calculations.

Comment: Thank you Oladya for the answer: yes, stupid me. I was thinking about something more complex (i.e. different memory management between sqlite.dylib and my code..)
I finished up refining my query like this `@"SELECT * FROM (SELECT distance(lat, lon, %f, %f) as distance, * FROM table) WHERE distance < %f ORDER BY distance DESC"` to have it ordered by distance. Cheers!

Comment: @AndreaCremaschi Add the solution in your post and mark it as closed or answered in order to remove it from the unanswered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in how the SQL Query was built, it should be:

`@"SELECT * FROM (SELECT distance(lat, lon, %f, %f) as distance, * FROM table) WHERE distance < %f ORDER BY distance DESC"`

(See the comments to the question for details)